# jQuery: Moving Li elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wrting following jQuery script which a click on a Li in the left div moves it to the right div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.left ul li').click(function(){
      var toAdd = $(this).html();
      $('.right ul').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
   });

    $(document).on('click', '.left ul li', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

It works perfectly. However if I try to do the same for the Li elements in the left div, so that after ckicking them they move to the left div, it doesnt work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.left ul li').click(function(){
      var toAdd = $(this).html();
      $('.right ul').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.left ul li', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

  $('.right ul li').click(function(){
      var toAdd = $(this).html();
      $('.left ul').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    });

  $(document).on('click', '.right ul li', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

This is the codepen link:

http://codepen.io/itsthomas/pen/hIfLD

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are trying to bind the click event to elements that don’t exist at that moment – `$('.right ul li')` selects no elements, because there _are_ no elements in your right UL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind event to element that do not exists.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('click', '.left ul li', function(){
        $(this).remove();
        var toAdd = $(this).html();
        $('.right ul').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    });  

    $(document).on('click', '.right ul li', function(){
        $(this).remove();
        var toAdd = $(this).html();
        $('.left ul').append('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    });  
});
```